# No agents were found with the following Xamarin.Android capabilities

Tags: xamarin, tfs, visual-studio-2017, tfsbuild

I'm trying to create a build definition to build and package an Android app based on Xamarin Forms.

I've installed Visual Studio 2017 and Xamarin on my build server, and even after restarting my server, my agent does not find the Xamarin.Android capability.

I'm still getting an error while queuing one build :

```
No agent could be found with the following capabilities AndroidSDK, MSBuild, 
Xamarin.Android, JDK
```

The only capability that is missing on my agent are  `Xamarin.Android`, `MSBuild` ,  `AndroidSDK`

I add the environnement variable "Xamarin.Android" , i restart the build agent ; but the same error

Do you have any idea on how to add it on my agent ?

Comment: If you know for a fact that it is available on the agent, you could add the capabilities on your agents user capabilities. Then try and see if the build definition works as intended.

Comment: i can't understanding you , the Xamarin.Android is added in the capabilities of the agent , i reboot my build server and my agent , but the same error

Comment: Can you then check and see [this link](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/1043) if it is the same problem you are having, it could be helpful

Comment: i don't have android sdk in my capabilities, how i can install them ?

Comment: Go to [this androiddocs website](http://www.androiddocs.com/sdk/index.html), scroll down to the bottom to the SDK Tools only part, select installer_r24.0.2-windows.exe for windows, download it and run the installer on your agent. When done, restart either the agent service or the machine and you should be set.